# Rspec: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

This is a piece of code which throws an error "Wrong number of args (1 for 0) on the 5-th line:

```
describe 'PATCH #update' do
  context 'title is empty' do
    it 'should not update page' do
      page = create(:page)
      patch :update, { id: page.id, page: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:page, title: nil) }, format: :json
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:unprocessable_entity)
    end
  end
end
```

Rails controller:

```
def update
    if @page.update(page_params)
      render json: @page
    else
      status :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

Other tests work just fine, but this for `#update's else` - doesn't .
Cant' get it, what's the problem and how can I fix this? (feature works just fine, but test fails)

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to fix this error, that's pretty obvious.

Comment: Isn't the `status :unprocessable_entity` should be  `render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity` ?

Comment: @Pavan, you're absolutely right. Thanks, post it as an answer, it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your `update` method to below

```
def update
 if @page.update(page_params)
   render json: @page
 else
   render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
 end
end
```